# What areas of the body are ervah according to law?

Tags: minhag, tanach, clothing, tznius-modesty

While custom can further bind what areas of the body need to be covered, when it comes to dress, is there a line that separates clothing that is *tzniut* from clothing that is not? For example, does clothing need to cover from the shoulders down to the knees in order to qualify as *tzniut*? [This essay](https://traditiononline.org/contemporary-tseniut/) (page 10) states:

> "According to the *Mishna Berura*, that which **law** (as opposed to
> custom) requires to be covered does not lose its *erva* status even if
> all women uncover it, whether or not *hirhur* is present" (emphasis
> mine).

With these things in mind, what areas of the body are *erva* according to law, regardless of culture and custom?

Comment: Are you asking besides genitalia? It's not clear there are any others.

Comment: @DoubleAA Of course there are others. For example, a married woman's hair, and a woman's upper arms (Kesubos 72a-b). And the *shok* (Berachos 24a).

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, I'm trying to know what areas of the body must always be covered regardless of custom.

Comment: @Meir To use the wording of the essay cited in my OP, would a married woman's hair be considered erva by custom or by law?

Comment: @TheEditor By law. The Gemara there derives the requirement to cover it from a verse in the Torah, and explains that on the level of *das Moshe* (Torah law) a basket (קלתה) would be a sufficient covering, but that on the level of *das Yehudis* (the customs accepted by Jewish women) something more is needed.

Comment: @Meir No, those sources don't say what you say they say

Comment: @TheEditor Meir just cited you a law for a married woman to wear a basket in some cases, but nothing about Ervah. Don't get confused by his citation-dropping.

Comment: Comments with an inappropriate tone have been and will be deleted.

Comment: @DoubleAA And since halachah requires it to be covered, then it's usually covered, and if it's not, then it's ervah.

Comment: @Meir that's a major logical leap not made in any rishonim or ShA afaik. Whether or not something is usually covered is not the same as whether or not it must be covered. (And I'll also note that the biblically required basket was at least partially see-through so the hair wasn't covered in the ervah sense anyway.)

Comment: Rabbi Willig's opinion is that the torso is unambiguously *ervah*, even in a culture where baring that is considered normal. Appendages depend on culture. (That is consistent with Rabbi YH Henkin's note that the base prohibition on arms is really bared shoulders, because that leaves the torso itself visible.)

Comment: @DoubleAA To help me better understand, where is the command for a basket in the Torah? Also, for an area of the body to be ervah, would that mean it must be covered regardless of custom?

Comment: @Shalom Would the thighs be considered ervah per Exodus 28:42 and Isaiah 47:2?

Comment: @Meir I'll also ask you the same: Would Exodus 28:42 and Isaiah 47:2 consider the thighs to be ervah?

Comment: @TheEditor The Talmud (Ketubbot 72), at least on the simple reading, derives a biblical obligation for married women to cover their heads from Numbers 5:18, and notes that a basket is sufficient to fulfill that obligation. Most rishonim understand the basket in question to not fully cover the head or to have many holes through which one can see her.

Comment: @Shalom R Willig's position is based solely on an original (IINM) and highly questionable diyuk of his in a rambam. Not a common position historically for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129468/discussion-between-the-editor-and-double-aa).